# AmplitudeJS setTimeout() with JSON callback

Tags: javascript, json, audio

I am trying unsuccessfully to understand how to set a time delay up between songs in AmplitudeJS.

Amplitude uses a JSON file for defining the songs and callbacks. In my case, it is a local JSON file:

From AmplitudeJS example:

```
var playCount = 0;
Amplitude.init({
"songs": [
{
"name": "Song Name 1",
"album": "Album Name",
"url": "/song/url.mp3",
"cover_art_url": "/cover/art/url.jpg"
},
{
"name": "Song Name 2",
"artist": "Artist Name",
"album": "Album Name",
"url": "/song/url.mp3",
"cover_art_url": "/cover/art/url.jpg"
},
{
"name": "Song Name 3",
"artist": "Artist Name",
"album": "Album Name",
"url": "/song/url.mp3",
"cover_art_url": "/cover/art/url.jpg"
}
],
//how the callback is setup in the example
"callbacks": {
'after_play': function(){
playCount++;
alert( playCount );
}
}
});
```

Here is a quote from the docs regarding the amplitudeJS callbacks:

> #### Callbacks There are a variety of callbacks that AmplitudeJS calls at certain times and the developer can bind to.
>
> | Callback        | Description|
>
> | --------------- |------------|
>
> | before_play     | Occurs before the play method is called|
>
> | after_play      | Occurs after the play method is called|
>
> | before_stop       | Occurs before the stop method is called|
>
> | after_stop        | Occurs after the stop method is called|
>
> | time_update         | Occurs when the time has updated|
>
> | album_change        | Occurs when an album changes|
>
> | song_change         | Occurs when a song has been changed|
>
> To bind to a callback you add a function to your callbacks object with
>   the key of one of the callbacks listed above. That key will be a
>   function. When the callback is called, the function the user passes
>   will be run.

I'm trying to add my setTimeout() method to the "song_change" callback. According to the way this works in AmplitudeJS, you add the callback at the end of the JSON file. Like this:

```
"callbacks": {
'after_play': function(){
playCount++;
alert( playCount );
}
}
```

One of the MANY things that I have tried is:
Var = timeOut (This is set at the top of the JSON file as is exampled by Amplitude docs.

```
"callbacks": {
'song_change': function(){
timeOut= setTimeout (5000);
}
}
```

I am just trying to set a delay between the songs.

Nothing works. Does anyone have any helpful comments or solutions for this problem? I've looked at every setTimeOut thread on stack overflow and searched all kinds of documents, but I can't seem to understand how to put this together.

I'm a designer at heart. I'm not a great shake as a coder. Please, be gentle, I don't know where else to post to find good help. I am trying. There is so little out there regarding AmplitudeJS. I can't find one forum devoted to it.

TIA -Rachel

Comment: please indent your code properly. You are using setTimeout incorrectly. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout you need to pass a function first, then `5000` for your 5 second delay.

Comment: I spent 90 minutes trying to get the question and code to display correctly. I guess it still didn't work. Wish there was a better place to ask these sorts of questions. Somewhere less professional and more for newer people. I try not to post here unless I simply can't get the answer alone. And..."Yes", I've read the mozilla docs a number of times and it doesn't make sense with how this is set up. Thanks.

Comment: I agree the code format tool which give 4 spaces for selected text is difficult to work with. As for setTimeout, you are passing in `5000` for the first parameter `setTimeout(5000)` which is invalid, because it expects a function first, and the delay duration second. Arguments are separated by *commas*. Here is an example: `setTimeout(function(){alert("5 seconds have passed!")}, 5000)`. the setTimeout itself returns an id (number) for the timeout. So timeOut probably contains `0`. You can use this id to stop the timeout if you want, with `clearTimeout(timeOut)`

Comment: @Noface Thank you for offering your help to me. I've tried to get the setTimeOut() to work. It doesn't seem to work for me in this situation. I probably just can't get the proper syntax. I can get a delay between songs using a for loop. Is there any reason not to do this:  "callbacks": {
    'song_change': function(){

     for(var count = 0; count < 2900000000; count++);
     }
 }

Comment: that's delaying based on cpu speed, so will be different for different computers etc. just don't do that. what is your setTimeout code looking like now?

Comment: does it automatically play the next song immediately on a song ending? in that case, does AmplitudeJs not have pause and resume functionality?

Answer (score 0):

How I'd approach this would be to do a callback for after the song changes like this:

```
"callbacks": {
  'song_change': function(){
    Amplitude.pause();

    setTimeout (function(){
      Amplitude.play();
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

What this will do is when the song changes, pause the active song and set a time out. When the 5 seconds (5000 ms) is up, it will play the song which will continue to the next song.  This should provide a proper delay. Hope this helps!

Comment: You made this so easy. I spent days trying to figure this out. I totally missed the pause. I'll try the fix as soon as I can get back to it.

Comment: Guess I'm just never going to get this stuff. I tried your fix but it didn't work for me. Maybe because, after fighting for a week everyday with "timeout()", I just went ahead and recorded my own delay in silence. I did notice that when I hit "pause" at the start of an audio, I would get the pause. I'll try recording without my own silence and see if that makes things different. Thanks again for trying to help. Even with no in delay, Amplitude helped me out a lot. -Rachel

Comment: I've tried everything and the above code isn't working. 1. Recorded without any silence pause at end using .m4a 2. Plugged my "Callout" into the Blue example. Only changed the url. 3. Recorded again using .mp3. 4. Copy and pasted the recommended code. There is no pause between callouts. I also tried using other callbacks. The only one that did anything was after_play and it simply stopped everything from progressing. Anymore ideas or help would be appreciated.